# Barra de rolagem vertical

Tags: html, css

Meu site está com uma barra de rolagem logo abaixo do Footer.

```
#main {

    display: -ms-grid;
    display: grid;

    grid-template-areas: "header header" "nav nav" "content aside" "footer footer" "privacidade privacidade";
}
```

`#main` é um id que coloquei no `section`, que está dentro do `body`, todo conteúdo do meu site esta dentro do `section`.

Alí no meu código tem o display `-ms-grid;` e o display `grid`. Se eu tirar o display `grid;` a barra de rolagem some, mas meu layout fica todo tronxo.

Eu não sei mexer com o prefixo `-ms-`, ele foi colocado aí no meu código por um um site auto prefix, pra ter compatibilidade com o IE.

Alguém me ajuda?

Comment: você quer tirar a barra é isso?

Comment: @JonyBoy Exatamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente adicionar `overflow-x:hidden;` no elemento que você quer, ou diretamente no `body` `body{overflow-x:hidden;}`

Comment: Ae, deu certo, vlw!